# Difference between S3 public files and static websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS S3 you can upload a file and make it public. You get a URL to access the same. Also, you can enable "Static Website Hosting". Can someone clarify the difference between these 2 approaches? If I can simply upload my html pages and make them public and access them over HTTP through browsers, why do I need to enable static website hosting ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enabling Static Website Hosting on S3 allows you to use a custom domain name, custom error pages, index.html documents for paths that end in `/`, and 301 redirects.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So, if I am in a quick need I can simply make files public and hand over to my customers. Apart from the custom domain name functionality, is there anything which is very limiting if I don't use static website hosting. Is there any major functionality which I won't get ?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just enable static website hosting. It doesn't matter if you are in a "quick need". It literally takes a couple seconds to enable it.

Comment: @RahulBansal the differences between the REST endpoint (which is always available) and the web site endpoint (which is only available when the static hosting feature is enabled for the bucket) are enumerated at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Comment: Thank you Michael. So, looks like there are minute differences, but nothing is so limiting that I can't host public pages w/o enabling static website hosting.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are just stumbling across this, one disadvantage of enabling Static Website Hosting is the HTTP only endpoint you get.

See [relevant docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). If you can work with the limitations of simply making the files public such as no custom domain name, you get TLS for free since some browsers block HTTP links on pages served over HTTPS.